# streamlit highcharts : how to show burger menu

Tags: python, highcharts, streamlit

I'm trying to reproduce code available here :
https://aalteirac-streamlit-highcharts-test-app-main-3vgde6.streamlit.app

I got the graph, totally working, except I don't get the burger menu allowing to download graph.

Can you advise on this question ?

I work on macOs, with python 3.11, streamlit 1.3 and streamlit_highcharts 0.2

Comment: You're not showing your code. Are you using the same [one](https://github.com/aalteirac/streamlit_highcharts_test_app/blob/master/main.py) used as an *example* by the library ?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue on my machine with a configuration of versions similar to yours.

It appears (*for a reason unknown to me*) that the exporting button was intentionally hidden by the library [`streamlit-highcharts`](https://github.com/aalteirac/streamlit_highcharts) itself, using CSS styling (the [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/display) is set to `None`).

To reveal the *ham-button*, you must comment out lines 4 to 6 in [this](https://github.com/aalteirac/streamlit_highcharts/blob/e5ab5d6d09c8b3965aebabe89490cab5b524804c/src/streamlit_highcharts/frontend/style.css#L4-L6) file (*locally*):

`streamlit_highcharts\frontend\style.css`

```css
text.highcharts-credits {
    display: none;
}
/* .highcharts-exporting-group {
    display: none;
} */
div[class*="chartMenu"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, you can build your chart :

```
import streamlit_highcharts as hg

hg.streamlit_highcharts(hg.SAMPLE2, 640)

assert "exporting" in hg.SAMPLE2 # True
```

***NB** : Make sure that your chart definition (*dict*) has an `exporting` key.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "burger" menu is associated with the [exporting module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview). So if you want to use it, you just need to import the [exporting module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview).

Docs: [https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/using-highcharts-for-python-basic-tutorial/#:~:text=Importing%20Highcharts%20for%20Python](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/using-highcharts-for-python-basic-tutorial/#:%7E:text=Importing%20Highcharts%20for%20Python)

Comment: I don't see how to modify my code (the same as the streamlit example).

Comment: I only gave a hint because I don't have much contact with Phyton. I think Timeless's answer and knowledge will be more helpful 